# How can I disable a form submission anchor when the inputs are invalid?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a couple of input text field on which I applied required and pattern and I use an anchor tag with `ng-click` to save the changes. The styling works well on the UI, when the input value does not meet the requirements the element becomes red. However the user is still able to click on the anchor. I want to be able to do one of 2 things, either disable the anchor when the input elements are not valid or in the `saveinfo()` function I want to be able to validate the input values without having to repeat the pattern and or required.

Here's what the html looks like:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="Name" required pattern="[a-zA-Z -]+" />
<input type="text" ng-model="Description" required />
<a ng-click="saveinfo()"><img src="./img/save.svg" /></a>
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300067/disable-submit-button-when-form-invalid-with-angularjs

Comment: why not add ng-disabled='form.$invalid' to your anchor tag?

Comment: Thanks for the tip guys, my problem was that I wasn't wrapping the elements in a form, once I did that I got it to work.

Thanks again.

Comment: Anchors should not be used to submit forms. Use buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use `ng-disabled='formName.$invalid'` on the anchor tag like where `formName` is name of form `<form name="formName"></form>`

```
<a ng-disabled='formName.$invalid' ng-click="saveinfo()"><img src="./img/save.svg" /></a>
```

OR You can check it inside the function as

```
    $scope.saveinfo= function(isValid) {

       // check to make sure the form is completely valid
      if (isValid) {
        alert('our form is amazing');
      }

    };

<a ng-click="saveinfo(formName.$valid)"><img src="./img/save.svg" /></a>
```