# How to prevent click event when parameter value is null in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

```
<input type="text" name="input" ng-model="email" placeholder="Email ID"/>
<!--input text box which value is send when click event fire.-->
<button type="submit" id="Button1" ng-click="sendBtnForgotPswd(email)" />
</form>
```

I don't want to fire click event when input "email" is undefined. Any in built filter provide by AngularJS for prevent click event*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable submit button when form invalid with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300067/disable-submit-button-when-form-invalid-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least two possibilities here. Probably optimal one is to use `ngDisabled` directive to deactivate button when email is empty:

```
<button ng-disabled="!email" ng-click="sendBtnForgotPswd(email)" 
        type="submit" id="Button1" >Send</button>
```

Other option is to call `sendBtnForgotPswd` function only when email is filled in:

```
<button type="submit" id="Button1" ng-click="email && sendBtnForgotPswd(email)">Send</button>
```

Also note that `button` tag cannot be self-closable so you should add closing `</button>`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ng-disabled="!email"` on the button element.