# disable button angular if $invalid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I cannot figure out why the following code isn't working.  I am following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300067/disable-submit-button-when-form-invalid-with-angularjs) and various other tutorials/answers but the button is not disabling when the fields are empty.

```
<h3>Add address</h3>
<div ng-include="'app/views/partials/form.html'"></div>
<button ng-click="ctrl.cancelAddress()">Cancel</button>
<button ng-disabled="addressForm.$invalid" class="save-btn" ng-click="ctrl.saveAddress(ctrl.name, ctrl.address, ctrl.country)">Save</button>
```

**app/views/partials/form.html**

```
<form name="addressForm" novalidate>
    <input ng-model="ctrl.name" type="text" name="RecipientName" required>
    <p ng-show="addressForm.RecipientName.$error.required">Username is required</p>

    <input ng-model="ctrl.address" type="text" name="AddressLineOne" placeholder="Address" required>
    <p ng-show="addressForm.RecipientName.$error.required">Address is required</p>

    <select ng-model="ctrl.country">
       <option ng-repeat="country in ctrl.countries" value="{{country.name}}">{{country.name}}</option>
       <p ng-show="addressForm.addressCountry.$error.required">Username is required</p>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: `addressForm` doesn't exist in the (outer) scope you are referencing it from. It can only be referenced within the `<form>` element where it exists. You need to put those controls inside the `<form>` anywhere for them to work.

Comment: @Amleonard is there anyway around this, as I have different actions depending upon whether I am editing or adding a contact

Comment: It depends, is your form aware of whether or not you are editing? Because if so, you can move those buttons into the form, and then use `ng-if="ctrl.isEditing"`. Of course, `ctrl.isEditing` would be replaced with whatever method you have of knowing if there is editing available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll put them as an answer for easier access.

`addressForm` doesn't exist in the (outer) scope you are referencing it from. It can only be referenced within the `<form>` element where it exists. You need to put those controls inside the `<form>` anywhere for them to work.

Is your form aware of whether or not you are editing? Because if so, you can move those buttons into the form, and then use `ng-if="ctrl.isEditing"`. Of course, `ctrl.isEditing` would be replaced with whatever method you have of knowing if there is editing available.