# How to disable upload button when there is no file selected in meteorjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor, angularjs-ng-disabled

I had tried `slideForm.$invalid` , but it's not working.Can you suggest the best way?

```
      <form name="slideForm">
          <div class="aboutFile">
             <input type="file" name="file" fileread="vm.file" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.file">
                <div class="create-component--perma-bg">
                  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   <span ng-if="!vm.file.name">Add File </span>
                   <span ng-if="vm.file.name">{{vm.file.name}}</span>
                </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info bgChangeBtnInfo" ng-
               click="vm.upload(vm.file)" ng-disabled="slideForm.$invalid"> 
                 Upload</button>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: instead of doing slideform.$invalid ; cant you take a variable ng-disabled="someVar" and then initially it will be false as the file might not be selected but when it is selected then assign it to true

Comment: i had tried that but it is still not working

Comment: can you please try slideform.file.$invalid ?

Comment: still not working any other way?

Comment: one easy way was as I said to create a variable in controller like vm.someVar=false; in html ng-disabled="someVar" and when u click the button do like someVar=true

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, does the current solution works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have to make it as required field  like this

```
<input type="file" name="file" fileread="vm.file" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.file" required>
```

Comment: Not working still uploading file and button is not disabled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300067/disable-submit-button-when-form-invalid-with-angularjs this might be helpful for you