# How to do validation in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to validation in angularjs and am trying to do it. Is it correct? Can anyone tell me?

```js
var app=angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('myController',function($scope){
$scope.clickMe = function(){
if($('#myForm .required').length==0){
alert("enter all details")
}

}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<form id="myForm" >
<input type="text" class="required">
<input type="date" class="required">
<select class="required">
<option>AAA</option>
<option>BBB</option>
</select>
</form>
<button ng-click="clickMe()">submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have added validation in your code for required field. To implement other validation please refer angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<form id="myForm" name="form1" ng-submit="form1.$valid && clickMe()">
<input type="text" class="required" name="text1" ng-model="model1" required>
<span ng-show="form1.text1.$error.required">Required</span>
<input type="date" class="required" name="text2" ng-model="model2" required>
<span ng-show="form1.text2.$error.required">Required</span>
<select class="required">
<option>AAA</option>
<option>BBB</option>
</select>
</form>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using angular form validations.
Here is an example.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function () {
        alert("My Form is valid");
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <form id="myForm" name="myUserForm">
        <input ng-model="mytext" type="text" class="required" required>
        <input ng-model="mydate" type="date" class="required" required>
        <select class="required" ng-model="myoption">
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="clickMe()" ng-disabled="myUserForm.$invalid">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300067/disable-submit-button-when-form-invalid-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 1):

Use validaton of angular:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.clickMe = function () { 
        if($scope.myForm.$valid) {
        alert("My Form is valid");
       }
    }
})
```

Now, because ng-model is a [Two-Way-Binding](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp)

You will have to supply name as well for your inputs so the validation will work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <form id="myForm" name="myUserForm">
        <input ng-model="mytext" type="text" name="mytext" class="required" required>
        <input ng-model="mydate" type="date" name="mydate" class="required" required>
        <select class="required" ng-model="myoption" name="myoption">
            <option>AAA</option>
            <option>BBB</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="clickMe()">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```